# Understanding expressions in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, expression

I am using an online textbook to learn the Scheme programming language. I am having trouble understanding the solution to an exercise in the textbook (Exercise 2.3.1. at [this page](http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Solutions/taxed-wage.html)). The Exercise is as follows:

> Utopia's tax accountants always use programs that compute income taxes
>   even though the tax rate is a solid, never-changing 15%. Define the
>   program tax, which determines the tax on the gross pay.
>
> Also define netpay. The program determines the net pay of an employee
>   from the number of hours worked. Assume an hourly rate of $12.

I made several attempts to complete it before resorting to the solution offered in the textbook (found [here](http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Solutions/taxed-wage.html)). The solution is as follows:

```
;; computes the tax    
(define (tax w)
  (* 0.15 w))

;; computes the net pay        
(define (netpay h)
  (- (wage h)
     (tax (wage h))))    

;; computes the wage for a given number of hours    
(define (wage h)
  (* h 12))    

;; EXAMPLES TURNED INTO TESTS
(tax 100) ;; should be 15
(wage 2) ;; should be 24
(netpay 40) ;; should be 408
```

This is the part of the code that has me confused:

```
(define (netpay h)
  (- (wage h)
     (tax (wage h))))
```

I do not understand why this expression works. I was expecting to see a mathematical operator before `wage` in `(wage h)` and before `tax` and `wage` in `(tax (wage h))`. The textbook doesn't mention this anomaly prior to this exercise. All previous examples look like `(* num1 num2)`. Can someone clear my confusion?  Thank You.

Comment: A mathematical operator in scheme is really just another function.  Remember, this isn't infix; it's not going to look like an ordinary mathematical expression. Think: `(function parameter)`

Comment: If there were an operator before `wage`, like `(+ wage h)`, what would that mean? How can you add a function to a number?

Comment: `(wage something)` means multiply `something` by 12.

Comment: @WickedJargon The expression `(wage x)` is *applying* the `wage` function to `x`.

Comment: What do `(wage h)` and `(tax (wage h))` mean in this expression? The textbook doesn't clearly state this prior to the exercise. And so I assumed `tax` and `wage` were both variables/numbers.

Comment: I understand, thank you. I only noticed your replies after my reply.

Comment: @WickedJargon `(wage h)` means `(* h 12)` and `(tax w)` means `(* 0.15 w)` because that's what they're defined to mean by their respective `define`s. So `(tax (wage h))` means `(* 0.15 (* h 12))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, there *is* a mathematical operator being used in those expressions, subtraction. The `netpay` function could also be written out like this:

```
(define (netpay h)
  (- (wage h) (tax (wage h))))
```

Is that more clear? In Scheme, whitespace is *insignificant*, which means that multiple spaces are equivalent to a single space, and linebreaks are equivalent to spaces. Basically, the *amount* of whitespace doesn't matter; it just serves as a generic seperator.

Scheme's prefix notation can sometimes be confusing before you get used to it. However, the basic idea is that all expressions are of the following form:

```
(f x ...)
```

This is equivalent to function application, also called "calling a function". In a C-like language, the syntax would likely look like this, instead:

```
f(x, ...)
```

The mathematical operators are just regular functions, so they share the same syntax. So, `(+ 1 2)` is 3 and `(* (+ 1 2) 3)` is 9 (see how they can be nested).

So, then, what does this expression do?

```
(- (wage h) (tax (wage h)))
```

It subtracts `(tax (wage h))` from `(wage h)`. In C-like syntax, this whole expression would look like this, instead:

```
wage(h) - tax(wage(h))
```